# Почему якоря имеют разное поведение при изменении высоты iframe?

Tags: веб-программирование, вёрстка, iframe

Помогите понять следующий момент.

Есть страница, которая подключается через iframe на другой странице.
Предположим, что верстка подключаемой страницы (iframe.html) имеет следующий вид:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iFrame</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        .inner__block {
            width: 100%;
            background: #f1f1b4;
            height: 100px;
            border-bottom: 3px solid black;
        }

        .test__block {
            width: 100%;
            height: 500px;
            background: #eceb51;
            border-bottom: 3px solid black;
        }

        h3 {
            margin-top: 0;
            padding-top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="inner__block">
        Очень большой iframe
        <br>
        <a href="#test">#test</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#test1">#test1</a>
        <br>
        <a href="#test2">#test2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="test" class="test__block">
        <h3>TEST</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="test1" class="test__block">
        <h3>TEST 1</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="test2" class="test__block">
        <h3>TEST 2</h3>
    </div>

    <div id="test3" class="test__block">
        <h3>TEST 3</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница, на которой находится iframe имеет следующую верстку:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
        .iframe {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 2131px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>

    <div>
        <iframe class="iframe" src="iframe.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

В таком сценарии переходы по якорям в iframe не срабатывают.

Но если уменьшить высоту iframe в стилях в два раза, то якоря начинают работать так, как надо.

Почему такое разное поведение работы якорей в зависимости от высоты iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Аналогично спросил на оригинальном StackOverflow и получил ответ, который совпал с моей теорией.

А именно ответ заключается в том, что документ в iframe является отдельным окном. И как любое окно в браузере - если контент полностью на виду, то и прокручивать не к чему. Это вполне нормальное поведение.

Ссылка на обсуждение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55844436/why-anchors-have-different-behavior-when-changing-iframe-heights#comment98351358_55844436